# Normal $\kappa$-complete non-principal ultrafilter on measurable cardinal $\kappa$

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory, filters, large-cardinals

Is it true that for every measurable cardinal $\kappa$ there is a normal, $\kappa$-complete, and non-principal ultrafilter on $\kappa$ ?

Comment: Yes, but this requires the axiom of choice. Bilinsky and Gitik constructed a model in which $\kappa$ is a measurable cardinal, but it does not carry any normal measure. I guess you can say it's a pretty crazy measurable. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. This can be shown in a more purely combinatorial way, but it's probably best to follow the proofs of

1. If $\kappa$ is measurable, then $\kappa$ is the critical point (i.e. least ordinal moved) of some nontrivial elementary embedding $j:V\to M$ where $M$ is an inner model.
2. If $j:V\to M$ is a nontrivial elementary embedding with critical point $\kappa$, then $\{X\subseteq \kappa: \kappa\in j(X)\}$ is a normal ultrafilter on $\kappa.$

This is all in Jech (as is a proof not using the elementary embedding characterization).